# Reports based on a Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to create a report not based on a table or query but on a form
The form has multiple Fields from table a, b, c and query x, y, z 
(all relating to what the end-user selects)..All those fields are combo-boxes

how do I create a report based on that form.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the form is open, you can refer to the form controls on the report. Create a textbox and set the Control Source to, say:

```
 =Forms!frmForm!txtText
```

Comment: Note: in the above "txtText" is the name of a field on the form.

Comment: @CarlF No it is not. It is the name of a control on the form.